# Mvc Drop Down List With Repository

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the id selected from a dropdown so that i can set it against my business logic method. I am using a repository pattern and my code is as follows.

However when i run the program, I get an error The insert statement conflicted with the foreign key.

> Database Table

```
public class Item
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ItemArtUrl { get; set; }


    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }

}
```

> Database table

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Item> Items { get; set; }

}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }        
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string ItemArtUrl { get; set; }


    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CategoryId")]
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoriesSelectListItem { get; set;}
}
```

> ViewModel

```
public class CategoryViewModel
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

> Business Logic Layer

```
public class ItemBusiness : IItemBusiness
{
    public void Insert(ItemViewModel item)
    {
        var itemrepo = new ItemRepository();
        Item i = new Item();
        i.Title = item.Title;
        i.Price = item.Price;
        i.ItemArtUrl = item.ItemArtUrl;
        i.CategoryId = item.CategoryId;
        itemrepo.Insert(i);
    }

    public List<ItemViewModel> GetAllItems()
    {
        var itemrepo = new ItemRepository();

        var query = (from x in itemrepo.GetAll()
                     select new ItemViewModel()
                     {
                         Title = x.Title,
                         Price = x.Price,
                         ItemArtUrl = x.ItemArtUrl,
                         CategoryId = x.CategoryId
                     }).ToList();

        return query;
    }
}
```

> Controller

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        var categoryBusiness = new CategoryBusiness();
        ViewBag.items = new SelectList(categoryBusiness.GetAllCategories(), "CategoryId", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ItemViewModel item)
    {
        var itemBusiness = new ItemBusiness();

        itemBusiness.Insert(item);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var itemBusiness = new ItemBusiness();

        return View(itemBusiness.GetAllItems());
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to insert a item whose category does not exist?

Comment: I want to insert an item and select its category from a dropdown

Comment: public List<CategoryViewModel> GetAllCategories()
        {
            var categoryrepo = new CategoryRepository();

            var query = (from x in categoryrepo.GetAll()
                         select new CategoryViewModel()
                         {
                             CategoryId = x.CategoryId,
                             Name = x.Name,
                             Description = x.Description
                         }).ToList();

            return query;
        }

Comment: Should I perhaps instantiate my CategoryViewModel as a list in my HttpGet Create controller and pass it in a viewbag to the view. Instead of getting the list of categories from my business logic method?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your Create view is set up to use ItemViewModel since you are returning it in the [HTTPPost] So instead of using ViewBag.Items = dropdownlist, set your ItemViewModel.CategoriesSelectListItem  to that list.

You would have to change your Controller to send an 'empty' ItemViewModel except with the CategoriesSelectionListItem

```
    public ActionResult Create()
{
    ItemViewModel ivm = new ItemViewModel();
    var categoryBusiness = new CategoryBusiness();
    ivm.CategoriesSelectionListItem = new SelectList(categoryBusiness.GetAllCategories(), "CategoryId", "Name");
    return View(ivm);
}
```

Then in your view set up the dropdownlist like this and it will return the CategoryId as part of the Model

```
    @Html.DropDownList("CategoryId", Model.CategoriesSelectListItem, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: var categoryBusiness = new CategoryBusiness(); used so that I can access GetAllCategories method, or is there an easier way

Comment: my bad!  You should have that in there.  I think this should work for you.  I would debug in Visual Studios and make sure everything is being set correctly on the way out [HttpGet] and then coming back in [HttpPost]